# How to get the latest updated currency rate from the table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to loop through this Model and get the value of rate based on latest updated currency rate. How can I do that?

```
@model IEnumerable<Ganedata.Core.Entities.Domain.TenantCurrenciesExRates>

<div id="LatestCurrencyExRate">

    @ViewBag.title
    <div id="CurrencyExRate">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div>
                @item.TenantCurrencies.GlobalCurrency.CurrencyName
                @item.TenantCurrencies.GlobalCurrency.Symbol
                @item.Rate
                @item.DateUpdated
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any errors, how it's not working?

Comment: You must show us your controller code. Your view is good but where is your currency rate datasource ?